# What would cause the system to report the following warning at boot: failed to connect to lvmetad, falling back to scanning?

Tags: linux, boot, lvm

I have just installed Kali linux, with LVM for volume management. It boots ok, but seems to throw up a warning about not being about to connect to lvmetad.

This question isn't just related to Kali linux, but also relates to Debian unstable branch and other Debian based distributions.

I understand lvmetad is a metadata cache to provide a journaled volume management layer in addition to a journaled fs, like ext4 etc.

Can someone shed some light on why is this likely occurring and how do I fix it? I have tried disabling lvmetad cache through some other postings I have read, nothing seems to fix this...

Comment: Is the service running for lvmetad?

Comment: Hardly a dupe, I haven't found it hard to install..                                    
So after a lot of digging I found out what is actually going on. Red hat patched LVM2 in 2013 to stop this warning whilst booting, lvmetad is not running at that moment in the boot process, hence the warning. it looks as if Debian haven't patched LVM2 or used the patch implemented by Red hat... the Red hat bugzilla is here for anyone else who has been trawling the internet for an answer: [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=813766)

Comment: @Kappy ah, you are welcome & indeed encouraged to post an answer to your own question on this site.  I found it quite easy to miss your comment.  For now, I am copying your comment & adding it as a community answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please read: [What is lvmetad and why would I want or need to use it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171733/276602)

You don't *need* lvmetad, however it is an important feature to reduce the likelihood of data loss in case of file system inconsistency or disk errors.

Answer (score 1):

> So after a lot of digging I found out what is actually going on. Red Hat patched LVM2 in 2013 to stop this warning whilst booting, lvmetad is not running at that moment in the boot process, hence the warning. It looks as if Debian haven't patched LVM2 or used the patch implemented by Red Hat... the Red Hat bugzilla is here for anyone else who has been trawling the internet for an answer:
>
> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=813766
>
> – Kappy